# Python subprocess module - unknown exception raised

Tags: python, linux, exception, module

Im getting an unknown exception from subprocess module in Python 2.6 on one of the servers.

Would like some help finding the issue here

Run the code:

```
ret = u.run('''echo''')
```

Where u.run is from here:

```
def run(cmd):
  cmd = '(' + cmd + ') 2>&1';
  info("Trying to run : " + cmd)
  try:
    ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    return ret
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    die("Error - Output:\n" + e.output + "\nExternal cmd return code: " + str(e.returncode) + "\nFor command: " + e.cmd)
  except:
    die("Unknown error running:\n" + cmd)
```

And my output is this:

```
Trying to run : (echo) 2>&1
DIE: Unknown error running:
(echo) 2>&1
```

Any ideas what is the "Unknown error?" There is no exception documented for subprocess other than CalledProcessError

Comment: Get rid of the `except:`, so that actual exception gets raised. Once you know what it is, you can handle that specifically. Or do `except Exception as e:` and print `e`.

Comment: Catch-all exception handlers are a bad idea in any language. There's a reason pylint, pychecker and every other static-code analyzer will tell you not to do a bare `except:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to catch exceptions but a catch-all `except` like that will make many programmers <strike>want to break your fingers</strike> very unhappy, because `Unknown error running: (echo) 2>&1` helps not at all.  The reason there's no information about the "unknown error" is because that's all you print.

There are two solutions: either let Python raise the exception itself (so you have a traceback and can figure out where you went wrong) or as @dano suggested above, print the actual exception in your handler like so:

```
def run(cmd):
  cmd = '(' + cmd + ') 2>&1';
  info("Trying to run : " + cmd)
  try:
    ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    return ret
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    die("Error - Output:\n" + e.output + "\nExternal cmd return code: " + str(e.returncode) + "\nFor command: " + e.cmd)
  except Exception as e:
    die("Uncaught error: " + str(e) + '\nrunning:\n' + cmd)
```

This will tell you what your error is so that you can either fix it (if it is a programming error) or create a specific error handler for whatever is causing you problems.